# Get visitor Latitude and Longitude from Google analytics through BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-maps, google-analytics, geolocation, google-bigquery

I've been using BigQuery (SQL)for a bit but now need to get some more specific location data. At the moment, our Google analytics table schema has the usual:
geonetwork.Metro, geoNetwork.region etc etc - but the geoNetwork.city data is pretty hit and miss.

So I'm wondering if anyone knows how I can grab Latitude and Longitude from the Google analytics that feeds into BigQuery. I've read that lat and long is available in the Google analytics real-time reporting API - but wondering if there's a way to get it into bigquery.

Any ideas would be awesome and much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

[BigQuery Export Schema](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en) is documented here and now contains lat/long columns.

Comment: Got it, thank you! I was actually looking to do a work-around and maybe grab it from the Google API and import into my table ... but struggling to find clear instructions on how to do it. I've just read it's possible.